# How can I different options on the header menu for logged in and logged out users on WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the OceanWP theme with wordpress to create my website.

The template I am using has two homepage menu bars, the main menu bar and the top menu bar, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/po0bi2

I only want to show the "my account" and "vendor dashboard" options on the top menu bar to logged in users, as well as the "log out" button. Currently they are showing for users both logged in or logged out.

I found some code online which I adjusted slightly and added to the functions.php file which should give the option to create two menus, one for logged in users and one for logged out users. Here is the code:

```
/* Menu location */
function prefix_menu_location() {

    // Register navigation menus
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'logged_in'     => 'Logged In',
        'logged_out'    => 'Logged Out',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'prefix_menu_location', 10 );

/* Menu for logged in and out users */
function prefix_top_menu_location() {

    $return = 'top_menu';

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $return = 'logged_in';
    } else {
        $return = 'logged_out';
    }

    return $return;

}
add_filter( 'ocean_top_menu_location', 'prefix_top_menu_location' );
```

After adding it it created a "logged in" and a "logged out" location in my menus page. please see: http://prntscr.com/po0fok

Also it gave me the option to select the options here on the edit menu page: http://prntscr.com/po0geh

I created two menus which I named "Top Bar menu 1" and "Top Bar menu 2", the second is the one I wanted to use for logged out users. The problem is it will only let me assign one menu to the top bar. Please see here: http://prntscr.com/po0j5t

When I set "Top Bar Menu 1" to the "top Bar" for users which are logged in, then I try to edit the "top Bar 2 Menu" for users which are logged out it will not let me also select the top bar as it says top bar is currently set to "Top Bar Menu 1" so when a user is logged in they will see the "top Bar Menu 1" but when they are logged out the top bar will be blank as it will not let me assign "Top Bar Menu 2" to the top bar. http://prntscr.com/po0ll2

Does anyone know how I can assign the second menu, for logged out users, to the top bar also or whether I need to change the code I added to the functions.php file?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your header.php file (or where ever your nav menus are displaying)

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'logged_in', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'logged_out', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or if you still want to do it in your functions file you can use this.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged_in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged_out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Comment: @Jas, have you had a chance to see if this is working for you? If so, and either option worked for you case, could you kindly accept this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Hi blupointmedia,
 thanks a lot for this. Just to clarify, regarding the code for the functions.php file, would I need to delete the code I added to use this or would I add it with the other code?

Comment: thankx, I tried replacing the other code I mentioned earlier in the thread, and also adding it alongside the other code but I still wasn't able to create separate menus for logged in/logged out users. I'm not sure what the code was meant to do?

Comment: I would comment out your code and use my function. If you have access to the child theme I would recommend trying it in the header.php file where the nav is being displayed. I have given two solutions in the same answer.

Comment: Ahh I see. thank you. Ok I deleted my code and I do have access to the child theme so I added your code to the header.php file:
http://prntscr.com/po5rre .

I am not sure if I added it to the correct place, I have changed it around a few times now but currently this is what happened to my site header: http://prntscr.com/po5sdc .

I was a little bit worried about playing around with it too much in case I messed up my site completely. Did I add it to the correct place? It is the "Top Bar" which I was wanting to change for logged-in/logged-out users.

Comment: Did you try removing your code and adding my first solution in your functions file? ...put your header file back the same way before this.

Comment: Ok, I have put my header.php file back as it was and then added your function to the function.php file: https://prnt.sc/po6426 .

My header and homepage has gone back to normal but I cannot figure out where to adjust the menu so that logged-in users and logged-out users have different options: http://prntscr.com/po664t .

I'm not sure whats changed?

Comment: You have to create two different menus one for logged in and a default (logged out) Then you set the ID's of the menu in the code I gave you for the function file. I put in logged_in and logged_out - but it may not be the id's you have

Comment: Hey blupointmedia, thank you so much! it worked:) That was amazing,

Comment: Hi blupointmedia, sorry about this but I am a newbie you see. Although the code does work and changes the menus for logged in and logged out users, I have just noticed that it is also changing the menus for the main menu as well as the top menu as it does here: http://prntscr.com/podv5e

I only wanted the top menu to change and the main menu to remain the same for both logged in and logged out users. I was just wondering whether there was a way to amend the code so that it only changed the top bar and not the main menu?

Comment: Um, there are two types of users. Either your logged in or logged out. The logged out menu should be your primary menu, so change the default logged_out to the primary menu id that you want all users to use and then use the logged in menu for the logged in user.

Comment: Ahh yes. I have changed the name of the primary (logged out) menu to "logged_out" and the logged in menu to "logged_in": http://prntscr.com/pogirq . I did this just to test it and it seems to be working. The primary menu shows when user is logged out and the logged_in menu shows when a user is logged in. Just to clarify, the problem is that the main menu, which is underneath the top menu also mirrors the top menu. I only wanted the top menu to change and not the main menu as the main menu has different options on it and I wanted it to remain the same either way. http://prntscr.com/pogjjd